# Dynamically generated divs from json file problems sharing link

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I am currently working on a real estate website, I wanted to make it easily maintainable. So I decided to create a website where all the listings dynamically generated from a JSON file. I gave an id property to the JSON, and a details button to the listings. To the button on click event I added a function which saves the id to a `localstorage` variable and opens a details page which is also dynamically generated using the same JSON data. My problem is that if I want to share the link it is obviously un-shareable because the details side needs an id number in order to know which details to be generated. Here is my code so far:

```
function addElement(appendIn, value) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "box";

  let {
    num,
    fokep,
    utcanev,
    kerulet,
    ar,
    kepekszama,
    ingtipus,
    ingallapot,
    negyzetmeter
  } = value;

  div.innerHTML = `
    <div class="thumb">

        <p class="total-images"><i class="far fa-image"></i><span>${kepekszama}</span></p>
        <p class="type"><span>${ingtipus}</span><span>${ingallapot}</span></p>
        <img src="${fokep}" class="img" alt="">
    </div>

    <h3 class="name">${utcanev}</h3>
    <p class="location"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span class="category">${kerulet}</span> Kerület</p>
    <div class="flex" style="justify-content:center; align-items:center">
            <p><span class="price">${ar}</span><i"> M Forint</i></p>
            <p><i class="fas fa-maximize"></i><span>${negyzetmeter} m2</span></p>
     </div>

    <a href="property.html" class="btn num" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-align:center;" data-filter="${num}" onmousedown="detailsClick(${num})">Részletek</a>

    `;
  appendIn.appendChild(div);
}

this
function generates all the listings on the main page it is called here

fetch('./database/houses.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {

    // iterating products
    for (let value of json) {
      addElement(grid, value)
    }

  });
```

The onclick function just saves the num aka id variable in a localStorage:

```
function detailsClick(num) {
    localStorage.setItem("idIndex", num);
    detailsIdClicked = num;
```

Then in the details page I use the same fetch method to get the details from the JSON file but only for the matching id numbered property

```
let num = localStorage.getItem("idIndex");

fetch('./database/houses.json')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(json => {

// iterating products
for(let value of json){
    if (num == value.num){

    addDetailedElement(grid, value);
    addheadElement(head,value);

    
}}
```

Then it generates the detailed div in the details page. But I just realized if I want to share a link from one computer to another, it obviously doesn't have the id number so it doesn't generate the same site. I wonder is there any solution for such problem? I have to admit I am quite new to web development and never before did any dynamically generated websites. I just realized this problem and now I am clueless about it. I was thinking of maybe append the URL link with the id number and then read the id number from URL to generate it, but if I do that the website doesn't load at all since there's no details1.html or details2.html only details.html

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` anymore. It is slow (reparsing DOM) and is open to security risks (XSS injections). Use `createElement` if you want to do it correctly or `insertAdjacentHTML` if you do not care for XSS injections risks

Comment: The problem is the way you're approaching this. Rather than store the variable in localStorage, use queryStrings in your links and then use javascript to parse them on the receiving page. That way you can have links like `https://website.com/property.html?id=123` that are shareable

Comment: @Kinglish Thank You for your help. i think i understand what you saying, but i am not sure how to implement it. Should i use queryStrings in my onclick function instead of the localStoreage.. and than use it on defining the num variable on the details.html site?

Comment: @tacoshy Thank you wery much.. i try to make this website as safe as possible. i didnt know that the innerHTML holds such danger, i will change the code as soon i figure it out my main problem . Thank You again ...its good to learn new things

Comment: A bit for a format shows this invalid code: `let {
    num,
    fokep,
    utcanev,
    kerulet,
    ar,
    kepekszama,
    ingtipus,
    ingallapot,
    negyzetmeter
  } = value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sharability, useability and accessibility, try using queryStrings. Your links could look like this:

```
<a href="/project.html?id=123">Get Details</a>
```

On the project.html page, use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to grab that id variable, like:

```js
// this line is just for testing
let url = new URL('https://test.com/project.html?id=123'); 
// you would use something like this:
// let url = window.location
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let id = params.get('id');
console.log(`the id is ${id}`);
```

Comment: Thank You very much that does the trick.. i was so desperate i thought i have to drop the dinamicly generated website id and redo the whole thing hard coded...